# Why "COUNT(*) WHERE LIKE" faster than "COUNT(*)"

Tags: mysql

I use MySQL and InnoDB. I want to know the number of all records in the table. It's about a million. There's a unique index on idx_user_name.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_user
SELECT COUNT(idx_user_name) FROM tb_user
```

And they takes 2.5s.[image: the explain result]

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_user WHERE idx_user_name LIKE "%%"
SELECT COUNT(idx_user_name) FROM tb_user WHERE idx_user_name LIKE "%%"
```

And it takes 0.3s. [image: the explain result] Why they are different?

Comment: You should run `EXPLAIN` on all 4 queries.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I would expect the first query also just scan the index - even mysql's optimizer should be able figure that out.

Comment: @Bohemian Agree...maybe the issue here is just a benchmark fluke, and maybe the performance is very similar across all 4 queries.

Answer (score 0):

Now run them in the opposite order.

A 10x speed difference usually comes from "caching".  2.5s to get all the data from disk; then 0.3s because that I/O is not needed.